# Regular Expression Negative Lookbehind Alternative for VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript

Since VBScript doesn't support lookbehinds, I'm looking for an alternative solution.

I have the string  '\E\F\'.

I want to replace \F\ with '~', but ONLY if it is not preceded by a \E.

After the substitution, I want '\E\F\' to be '\E\F\'.

If the string was 'randomText\F\', I would want it to look like 'randomText~' after the substitution.

Solution:

I just decided to StrReverse it and do a negative forward lookahead.  It's not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work in this case.

```
Dim regEx, str1
str1 = StrReverse("The quick \F\ brown \E\F\ dog.")
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Pattern = "\\F\\(?!E\\)"
regEx.Global = True
ReplaceTest = regEx.Replace(str1, "%")
```

Comment: Different regexp libraries have different syntax. What are you feeding your regular expressions to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[VBScript doesn’t support look-behind assertions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) But try this:

```
(^.?|[^\\].|\\[^E])\\F\\
```

Or this:

```
(^.?|(?!\\E)..)\\F\\
```

Replace the match with `$1~` (first submatch and `~`).

Here’s an explanation: In general there are two situations: If there is no or just one character before `\F\` (`^.?`), everything is ok. But if there are at least two characters before `\F\`, we need to make sure, that these characters are not `\E`. So we say, that the two preceeding characters are either

- any character except `\` followed by any arbitrary character (`[^\\].`), or
- `\` followed by any character other then `E` (`\\[^E]`).

That construct ensures that every other combincation except `\E` is allowed.

The same applies to the second expression. But here we use the negative look-ahead assertion to ensure that the two characters before `\F\` is not `\E`.

Comment: The quick \F\ brown FF\E\F\ dog. Turns to The quic~ brown FF\E\F\ dog.

Comment: @Chris: You need to replace the match with the first submatch and `~`, so `$1~`.

Comment: Sorry.  Missed that.  They seem to work at first glance.  Let me try to decipher them and do some testing.  Then, I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Nice one!  Or should I say "Nice *two*"? :)  I would have left out the '?' in `\\[^E]?` but it seems to work either way.

Comment: They seem to work.  If you could give a quick summary of one of them, I'd appreciate it.  I have some knowledge of regex, but I'm struggling to understand the solutions completely.

Answer (score 0):

you want a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!\\E)\\F\\
```

Comment: Though I think you need an extra \\ at the end

Comment: VBScript (and JavaScript and JScript) regular expressions don't support lookbehind (http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html). you might find some alternative googling for "VBScript Lookbehind". or change to a language that does support it (http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html , search for "Lookaround")

Comment: VBScript does not support lookbehind, and the OP explicitly asked for alternative for it.

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev The original question (which I answered) didn't mention lookbehind: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1357769/1

Answer (score 0):

don't have to use regex. here's one solution

```
strString = "The quick \F\ brown \E\F\ dog"
s = Split(strString," ")
For i=1 To UBound(s)
    If Not InStr(s(i),"\E\F")> 0 And InStr(s(i),"\F") > 0 Then
        s(i) = "~"
    End If 
Next
strFinal=Join(s," ")
WScript.Echo strFinal
```

output

```
C:\test>cscript /nologo test.vbs
The quick ~ brown \E\F\ dog
```