# JS regexp (?<!X)A

Tags: javascript, regex, posix

Does anyone know how translate the POSIX regexp `(?<!X)A` in JS?

Find A only if not preceded by X.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript.

Comment: I don't think that negative lookbehinds are in POSIX, lookarounds are not supported in BRE nor ERE. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Simply check for either the beginning (ergo there is no X) or that there is a non-X character.

```
(^|[^X])A
```

For more than one character, you could check for `A` and then check the matched text for X followed by A, and discard the match if it matches the second pattern.

Comment: +1 This will behave the same unless the global modifier is on.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't.

JavaScript's `RegExp Object` does not support negative lookbehind.

- [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)
- [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390037/javascript-regular-expressions-lookbehind-failing)

Comment: @dotweb, -1, it does not, and your answer does not prove otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "ab"; 
console.log(/a(?!x)/i.exec(str)); //a

var str = "ax"; 
console.log(/a(?!x)/i.exec(str)); //null
```

if you need of part after "a", try:

```
   /a(?!x).*/i
```