# VBScript Regular Expression: Negative Lookbehind: Match VBScript Method Declarations Not in Comments

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to construct a regular expression using VBScript to extract VBScript method declarations that aren't commented out. For instance, consider the following methods:

```
Public Function thisContainsACommentedRoutine()
''   Public Sub myRoutine1()
''       print "hello"
''   End Sub
    thisContainsACommentedRoutine = 1 + 1
End Function

'Public Sub myRoutine2()
'    print "routine2"
'End Sub

    Private Sub sub1()
        print "sub1"
    End Sub
```

I want the following method declarations to be extracted:

```
Public Function thisContainsACommentedRoutine()
Private Sub sub1()
```

I tried using the following regular expression (along with many others; I tried researching with negative look-behinds, but they aren't supported in VBScript, so I also tried negative look-aheads):

```
(?!')(Public|Private) (Function|Sub) .*
```

using http://regexpal.com, but all the method declarations are being extracted, and I want to ignore any lines that contain the comment character before the method declaration.

The code in the first code block above is returned to me as a whole string, and I'm using VBScript's regular expression object to execute the pattern on the whole string of methods. Also, I'd like to avoid having to process one line at a time to save time.

I tried looking up similar questions ([Regular Expression Negative Lookbehind Alternative for VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357769/regular-expression-negative-lookbehind-alternative-for-vbscript)), but somehow the negative lookahead regular expression I'm using is still grabbing the methods that are commented out.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I'm using .NET's regular expression object instead, and that supports negative lookbehind assertions. I'm now using the following regular expression:

```
\s*?(?<!')\s*?(Public|Private) (Function|Sub) .*
```

However, I'm still getting incorrect matches:

```
Public Function thisContainsACommentedRoutine()
Public Sub myRoutine1()
Private Sub sub1()
```

The match "Public Sub myRoutine1()" should not be showing up; regardless of the number of spaces before the method, I don't want the method to match if there is at least one comment character (anywhere in the line) before the method declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript is line orientated. So you can try to exploit that feature by using a Multiline (VBScript) RegExp as in:

```
  Dim sAll : sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\testdata\subfnc.txt").ReadAll()
  WScript.Echo sAll
  WScript.Echo "--------------"
  Dim reSF : Set reSF = New RegExp
  reSF.Global     = True
  reSF.IgnoreCase = True
  reSF.Multiline  = True
  reSF.Pattern    = "^\s*((?:(?:Public|Private)\s+)?(?:default\s+)?(?:Sub|Function).+)\r$"
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT in reSF.Execute(sAll)
      WScript.Echo qq(oMT.SubMatches(0))
  Next
```

output:

```
Public Function thisContainsACommentedRoutine()
''   Public Sub myRoutine1()
''       print "hello"
''   End Sub
    thisContainsACommentedRoutine = 1 + 1
End Function

'Public Sub myRoutine2()
'    print "routine2"
'End Sub

    Private Sub sub1()
        print "sub1"
        print "Private Sub Sub2(abc)"
    End Sub

         Sub Nix
         End Sub ' Nix

 Public Default Function Zilch(Whatever)
End Function

--------------
"Public Function thisContainsACommentedRoutine()"
"Private Sub sub1()"
"Sub Nix"
"Public Default Function Zilch(Whatever)"
```

If your code contains Sub/Function declarations spanning lines (_ abomination), you have to pre-process the file(s); then you could remove comments radically (and still use the pattern given above).

Comment: I was actually able to use the following regular expression to obtain my answer:

`(?<!('+?)\s*?)(Public|Private) (Function|Sub) .*`

But I didn't know about the MultiLine property in the regular expression object for VBScript. Thanks!